# Android : How do I know if the adb shell input text is completed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have an input field where I set the data by using adb shell and I want to know if the adb shell input text is completed or not. So if it is completed then I want to write some logic. For EditText, we have addOnTextChangeListener, addTextChangeListener, OnEditTextSubmitListener. I have tried all the three options. addOnTextChangeListener got triggered for every character. It applies to addTextchangeListener as well. OnEditTextSubmitListener is not firing in some android devices. Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure of your setup. You have a device with your app on it, connected to a PC and the PC is running "adb shell input text"? Maybe you could wait for addOnTextChangeListener to have been triggered but not being triggered for ex 200 ms?

Comment: @hanlog Thanks for your reply. I am using a third party library which is setting the text after the successful laser scan (qr code)from my app. I am not setting the data using settext. So I assume the library itself runs the adb shell command to set the text to my inputview. I have tried 200ms already. But the user also have the option to manually enter the input. In that case it will trigger for every chanracter. So I have a problem here.